# All Day Event = False throws a workflow error

Tags: workflow, date-time

I have a workflow item that I am stumped on.

It is very basic...

```
1 If All Day Event equals True
2   Log >SET TIME<
3   then Store [%Date%] in Variable:TimeFrame
4   then Log - OK
5 Else If All Day Event equals False
6   then Log >SET TIME 2<
7
8   then Log - OK
```

For line 7, I initially had another then store statement (similar to line 3), but it the else statement keeps erroring out so I removed all code and left just the log.

When the item is an all day event, it works perfectly fine.  As soon as it is a partial day event, it generates a workflow error every time even if no code other than the log is being set.

Is there an issue in how I am assessing the "all day event equals false"?  I also tried to remove the condition entirely (line 5) hoping that if it was not an all day event it would run the code, it still errored out immediately after running line 6.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appeaars it was an issue of mixed variable types.  It is now resolved.